# is there better way using rxjava with multiple requests?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm new in rxjava or rxandroid, and looking for a better way dealing with multiple requests. I need to get the token from server and use the result as a parameter to do login verification and if it returns success then get the sessionId through getSessionId method.
I've considered about zip or merge, but I don't think it'll work. So can you give me an idea or I don know , train of thought? 
Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
private void getToken(final String name , final String pwd){
    api.newToken()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<TokenModel>() {
      @Override public void call(TokenModel tokenModel) {
        String token = tokenModel.request_token;
        if (!"".equals(token)){
          login(token, name, pwd);
        }else {
          Timber.e("got token failed");
        }
      }
    });
  }

private void login(String token, String name, String pwd){
    api.validateToken(token, name, pwd)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<TokenModel>() {
      @Override public void call(TokenModel tokenModel) {
        String token = tokenModel.request_token;
        if (!"".equals(token)){
          getSessionId(token);
        }else {
          Timber.e("got token failed");
        }
      }
    });
  }

private void getSessionId(String token){
    api.newSessionn(token)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<TokenModel>() {
      @Override public void onCompleted() {
        //go to home activity
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        //handle error
      }

      @Override public void onNext(TokenModel tokenModel) {
        //store session id
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first subscription call your second subscription, ...
You can avoid this using flapmap operator.

```
api.newToken(...)
     .flapMap(token -> api.validateToken(token))
     .flapMap(token -> api.newSession(token)).subscribe()
```

New observable in a subscription can offen be replaced by a flatMap call.

If you want to manage your error, in a flatMap, if the token is invalid, your can return an error observable instead of returning new api call observable.

```
.flatMap(token -> if(token.isValid){ return api.newCall(); } else { return Observable.error(...); ;)
```

Comment: Thank you , it helps a lot.  By the way, can I handle the errors all in Observer? you know, the onError().

Comment: It depends but you can